# Flutter: TextFormField - set input type to time instead of dateTime

Tags: flutter, dart, android-textinputedittext, flutter-text

I am migrating an android app to flutter. Now i have a textFormField, and the input type is supposed to be of 'time' type. But unlike android there is no option in flutter to set the input type to time, only dateTime is available. I have shared some pics of my android and flutter project:

Android time:

[image: android time]

Flutter dateTime:

[image]

I want android type editText in flutter TextField. Have someone tried it or is it possible?

Thanks for help!

Comment: why don't you try time picker dialog?

Comment: actually i want to migrate the android project to flutter without any changes.

Comment: I think flutter doesn't have that inputtype. In flutter they use timepicker for time and datepicker for date. Just pickers they use.